# Window setContentView Crash?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've no idea why but whenever I do a simple:

```
[_window setContentView:newView];
```

I get a 'gdb' crash.

I have two methods, 'enterFullscreen', 'exitFullscreen', where _window is my main NSWindow.

```
NSView *oldView;

- (void)enterFullScreen:(NSView*)newView
{
    oldView = [[_window contentView] view];
    [_window setContentView:newView];
}

- (void)exitFullscreen:(NSView*)newView
{
    [_window setContentView:oldView];
}
```

These 2 methods are linked to 2 Push Buttons with an IBAction. Whenever I press the button, the views swap over but is followed by a crash straight away.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks everyone

**EDIT: This is the code I now have:**

```
-(void)enterFullscreen(NSView*)newView
{
    oldView = [[NSView alloc] init];
    oldView = [_window contentView];
    [newView removeFromSuperview];
    [_window setContentView:newView];
}

- (void)exitFullscreen:(NSView*)newView
{
    [_window setContentView:oldView];
}
```

Entering fullscreen works fine, but when I invoke exitFullscreen, the Window goes blank and then results in the following crash:

[image: crash image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's no such thing as a “gdb crash”. GDB is the debugger. The only way you would have a GDB crash is if the debugger itself crashed—and then you wouldn't be looking at it in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

The code as posted won't compile. There are missing colons or I'm not understanding the method signatures in some other way.

Second, `[window contentView]` returns an `NSView`.  You then invoke a `-view` method on it.  What's that?  `NSView` doesn't have such a method.  And from the context, you mean to save the actual old content view in `oldView`, so why are you invoking something beyond `[window contentView]`?

Anyway, the window retains its content view.  However, when you swap in a new content view, it releases the old one and retains the new one.  If you're using ARC and `oldView` isn't `__strong` or if you're not using ARC, then the old content view is not retained by anything and is deallocated.

If that doesn't explain it, you need to post the exact exception, crash, or error message and show where it's happening.

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing a colon somewhere I re-wrote the code because mine is far larger. If I understand you, changing the unsafe_unretained to _strong on the views will fix this?

Comment: ARC says it does not allow __strong?

Comment: Where does it say it? What did you try?

Comment: I changed from unsafe_unrestrained to __strong in the .h file and I got an error saying disallowed by ARC. However even if I put in 'assign' or 'retain' in the .h file I get the same crash.

Comment: You changed it where? On an instance variable declaration? On a property declaration? Saying you changed a word in a file is not exactly informative. When you get a compiler error **show the error verbatim and the line which provoked it**.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. I changed it on a property declaration. I'll try and find how I get the line which provoked the error now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The crash occurs when I setContentView.

Comment: OK, on a property declaration you use `strong` without leading underscores. You also need to actually use the property by invoking the setter like either `[self setOldView:[window contentView]]` or `self.oldView = [window contentView]`.

Comment: Ok good news, I've put 'strong' on all the NSViews and now the application doesn't crash when I change views, thank you very much I learned something. I am however having another problem, when I change back to the old view, the view is empty? So basically if I fullscreen one of the views, and then exit, that view is gone? Thanks again Ken

Answer (score 0):

setContentView; send an autorelease message. This method causes the old content view to be released; if you plan to reuse it, be sure to retain it before sending this message and to release it as appropriate when adding it to another NSWindow object or NSView.
 Try something like the following.

```
  [newView retain];
  [oldView removeFromSuperview];
  [_window setContentView:newView];
  [newView release];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but my project is using ARC and I therefore can't retain